# Multiple Arguments for Views for Contextual

Tags: views

I have a special path_alias for my content in the form of /profiles/username/1234.

When a user goes to /profiles/username it goes to one view. Usernames are a taxonomy vocabulary
- That view has a path as /profiles/% and I validate that argument against the term id.

When a user goes to /profiles/username/1234, I would like it to go to a special view just for that node.
- I tried doing /profiles/%/%, and created two contextual views - one similar to the first view for profiles but having "Provide default value" and "Raw value from URL" and path component 2 (for /profiles/%); 2nd contextual view was same format, but with path component 3 (for /profiles/%/%) and that validating to Content, my content type, and filter value format as "Node ID"

Doesn't seem to override the normal node display with my view.

Any advice would be super helpful thanks!

Comment: Views are typically used for creating lists of several nodes. Can you clarify what you gain by displaying a single node with a view?

Comment: Also, would be interesting to hear why you use terms for usernames instead for actual users or maybe some dedicated content type, like customers or members.